# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.sun.prism.ResourceFactory.isDisposed()' JavaFX

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I had a perfectly well running non-maven JavaFX project, till I decided to convert it into a Maven project in Eclipse.

Now, I created the Maven run configuration and added the same VM arguments in JRE section of Maven run configuration:

```
--module-path "C:\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib"  --add-modules=javafx.swing,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml,javafx.media,javafx.web --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.charts=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.iio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.iio.common=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.css=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.runtime=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism=ALL-UNNAMED
```

based on some answers. However I am getting the error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.sun.prism.ResourceFactory.isDisposed()'
```

To overcome it, even added a maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
```

But no use.

My error log is :

```
    Jun 30, 2021 4:16:49 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 15.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 11
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.sun.prism.ResourceFactory.isDisposed()'
    at javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCPageBackBufferImpl.validate(WCPageBackBufferImpl.java:99)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.WebPage.paint(WebPage.java:703)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.web.NGWebView.renderContent(NGWebView.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:479)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:328)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.sun.prism.ResourceFactory.isDisposed()'
    at javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCPageBackBufferImpl.validate(WCPageBackBufferImpl.java:99)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.WebPage.paint(WebPage.java:703)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.web.NGWebView.renderContent(NGWebView.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:479)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:328)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.sun.prism.ResourceFactory.isDisposed()'
    at javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCPageBackBufferImpl.validate(WCPageBackBufferImpl.java:99)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.WebPage.paint(WebPage.java:703)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.web.NGWebView.renderContent(NGWebView.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:479)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:328)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.sun.prism.ResourceFactory.isDisposed()'
    at javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCPageBackBufferImpl.validate(WCPageBackBufferImpl.java:99)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.WebPage.paint(WebPage.java:703)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.web.NGWebView.renderContent(NGWebView.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:479)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:328)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  40.897 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-30T16:17:24+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Anyone who has faced similar issue ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a case of missing packages. So first I had to amend the runtime arguments to:

```
   --module-path "C:\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib"  --add-modules=javafx.swing,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml,javafx.media,javafx.web --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.charts=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.iio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.iio.common=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.css=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.runtime=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism=ALL-UNNAMED
 --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.impl=ALL-UNNAMED
 --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.impl.shape=ALL-UNNAMED
 --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism=ALL-UNNAMED
 --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.paint=ALL-UNNAMED
```

and then as when when "no such method error " came, found the relevant dependency & update the POM.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, It was due to version incompatibility between javafx.web, javafx-swing and javafx-controls modules.
I was using `javafx-controls` version 14, I changed it to 19 and it worked

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
```

check the latest dependency here
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-swing